# SQL group-by largest

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, group-by

I have a table that has cooccurrence counts by objects that looks like the following:

```
col1    col2    count   
item1   item2    3
item3   item2    1
item1   item4    1
item2   item3    2
```

I would like to do a group-by largest top n counts on col1, however if I do that on the above table since all object pairs are not available the result would be the following: **(which is not correct)**

```
col1    col2    count   
item1   item2    3
item3   item2    1
item2   item3    2
```

If I swap the columns and then add them back to the same table this would be the result:

```
col1    col2    count   
item1   item2    3
item3   item2    1
item1   item4    1
item2   item3    2 
item2   item1    3
item2   item3    1
item4   item1    1
item3   item2    2
```

And the group by would yield: **(the correct result)**

```
col1    col2    count   
item1   item2    3
item2   item1    3
item4   item1    1
item3   item2    2
```

What would the proper query be for producing this kind of group-by? Am I correct that the column would need to be swapped and concatenated or is there a better way to go about this? (I'm using Postgres)

**In the above I am showing a group by top 1, for the sake of keeping the example simple, in reality this is a group by top 10**

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

I *think* you want:

```
select v.col1, v.col2, max(t.count)
from t cross join lateral
     (values (col1, col2), (col2, col1)) v(col1, col2)
group by v.col1, v.col2;
```

Comment: Just one clarification, I am looking to do a top 10 largest group-by